# Laravel package dependency not loaded

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have trouble getting my package dependencies to install in vendor folder. See files below. Starting from a clean laravel 5.5

/packages/anders/pack/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "anders/pack",
    "description": "A test package",
    "type": "laravel",
    "require": {
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Adding my package manually to /composer.json to test it out while developing:

```
...
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Anders\\Pack\\": "packages/anders/pack/src"            
}
...
```

At this point I should be good to do a composer update at project root? But the yajra dependency is not installed. I have tried composer dumpautoload, deleting lock files and clearing cache without success. Running composer update inside the package installs it just fine so json is valid.

I do not think its a problem but here is my service provider

```
namespace Anders\Pack;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PackServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {   
        require __DIR__ . '/routes/web.php';
    }

    /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This works just fine, it adds an extra route to the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer won't resolve dependencies of your **auto loaded** packages. You need to add those dependencies manually to your root composer.json

Answer (score 2):

You need to following steps, to solve this issue :

1. Run the `composer update` command in your packages directory.
2. Now use this in your package (on top of the file) whenever you want to use this dependency `use Yajra\DataTables\yourDependency`